# Unexpected end of JSON input after HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here I'm making a HTTPS request and storing the JSON sent back in the `data` variable. I have used a similar function elsewhere in the program where it worked as expected. However this time I'm getting a `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` on the line where is use `JSON.parse(data)`.

I suspect `data` doesn't contain all of the JSON sent back from the API since it is quite large. Do I need to change how I capture the input from the HTTPS request incase it is not all captured into `data` in one go or is there some other issue here?

The only thing making my question the code instead of the API is that when making the request on a third party HTTP client I get all the JSON expected.

```js
function isStreamLive(channelID, callback) {
    isLive = false;
    const optionsStreamInfo = {
        'hostname': 'api.twitch.tv',
        'path': '/kraken/streams/' + channelID,
        'headers': {
            'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'
        }
    }
    const request = https.get(optionsStreamInfo, (result) => {
        result.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
    request.end();
}
```

The output before the program terminates shows the vast majority of the JSON expect but cuts off and is followed by a few blank lines.

Logging the `data` variable without using JSON.parse shows

```
<Buffer 7b 22 73 74 72 65 61 6d 22 3a 7b 22 5f 69 64 22 3a 33 38 31 34 30 30 37 33 38 30 38 2c 22 67 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 44 6f 74 61 20 32 22 2c 22 62 72 6f 61 ... 
1321 more bytes>
<Buffer 76 69 65 77 73 22 3a 34 38 37 38 39 31 32 2c 22 66 6f 6c 6c 6f 77 65 72 73 22 3a 39 31 30 33 39 2c 22 62 72 6f 61 64 63 61 73 74 65 72 5f 74 79 70 65 ... 
84 more bytes>
```

From this I assume that JSON.parse is taking in the first Buffer and not the second leading to the JSON being cut off.

Is there a way to get take in these two buffers at the same time?

Comment: What could you do in the logic to allow yourself to see what the value of `data` actually is?

Comment: Why not console.log(data) before trying to parse it to see what's in the response (or use Developer tools to inspect the request/response)? Either way, I suspect you're correct that the server is sending you malformed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to end the request.

You can do something like this:

```
function isStreamLive(channelID, callback) {
    isLive = false;
    const optionsStreamInfo = {
        'hostname': 'api.twitch.tv',
        'path': '/kraken/streams/' + channelID,
        'headers': {
            'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'
        }
    }
    const request = https.get(optionsStreamInfo, (result) => {
        result.on('data', (data) => {
            const mergedData = Buffer.concat(data)
            console.log(JSON.parse(mergedData));
        });
    });
}
```

Using Request-promise, you can also use node-fetch, its very similar..
    const rp = require('requrest-promise');

```
const optionsStreamInfo = {
    uri: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${channelID}`,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'
    },
    json:true // this should take care of this buffer business
}

return rp(optionsStreamInfo).then((res)=>{
    console.log(res)
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: It doesnt seem I can use .then in this case (https.get(...).then is not a function). Is there an alternative?

Comment: what package are you using to make the request?

Comment: HTTPS. I tried using request earlier but struggled with it. Also I don't think im running out of memory since the size of the full JSON is around 2Kb.

Comment: can you log out data instead of JSON.parse(data)?

Comment: That doesn't lead to errors but instead just shows the raw hex and using JSON.stringify just makes a list of numbers. They do both show that there are two buffers, one much larger than the other. So I assume JSON.parse is just parsing the first buffer and leaving the second which is leading to the JSON being cut off. So I think the way to the fix is figuring out how to parse both buffers at once or getting all the JSON into a single buffer

Comment: is data an array of buffers? I have modified my answer to include a promise version and a non promise version both assuming that data is an array of buffers. For the promise version you can `npm install request-promise` to make it work